# Populate ListView with text and value from strings.xml

Tags: android, arrays, string, listview

I'm new to android and want to populate listview items that have id as value and string as caption.
All I could find searching was that they suggest using string array like:

```
<string-array name="test">
      <item>first item</item>
      <item>second item</item>
</string-array>
```

What i'm looking for is something like:

```
<string-array name="test">
      <item value="1">first item</item>
      <item value="2">second item</item>
</string-array>
```

just like the `option` tags of a `select` in html

Comment: `ArrayAdapter` accepts a `String[]`. You can get a `String[]` from the XML resources. What exactly are you having problems doing that?

Comment: @cricket_007 well as I said I'm new to android. then I might be looking for another `view` other than `listview`. is there a view that can have text and value for each item?

Comment: Similar question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18827470/creating-arrayadapter-using-xml-resource-and-retrieving-id-or-value-fields-u

Comment: You can simply adjust the Adapter's row layout view to display a number value (like the position of the element) next to each item. The ListView isn't the problem, it is simply the display element of the Adapter (where the data is held)

Comment: well the values are not ordered. first item may have value of `8` and the second one `4`

Comment: And this has to be from XML resources? You could do something like this quite easily with plain Java objects or Sqlite

Comment: well how would it be done without XML resource?

Comment: Have a class holding an ID and a Value. Load a List of that class into an ArrayAdapter. Or do the same with a SQLite table with 2 columns (and use CursorAdapter). And there's probably more ways... I simply asked if the XML was necessary

Comment: nope its not necessary. let me test your solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a new Activity (this will make a xml file (layout) and a Java class.

On the layout, create a Layot that has a ListView on int:

```
<?xml version=”1.0” encoding=”utf-8”?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android=”http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android”
    android:layout_width=”match_parent”
    android:layout_height=”match_parent”
    android:orientation=”vertical” >

 <ListView
    android:id=”@+id/itemList”
    android:layout_width=”match_parent”
    android:layout_height=”wrap_content” 
    android:entries="@array/test"
/>
```

On your activity, you have to:

- Create a ListView variable
- Map your view on the XML on this variable
- Get a list of Strings from your resource array-adapter
- Instanciate an Adapter (an object that you have to set on your listview to get your list (in your case, of strings) and add them in your recycler view. You can create a customized class for your adapter it, but when dealing with Strings, you can use a simple one called ArrayAdapter).
- Set your adapter on your ListView object

To do all of those things, you put this in your code:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    // Creating variable
    ListView listView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Mapping with your XML view
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.itemList);

        /// Getting list of Strings from your resource
        String[] testArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.test); 
         List<String> testList = Arrays.asList(test);

        // Instanciating Adapter
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getBaseContext(),
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, testList);

        // setting adapter on listview
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to get the items from the resources

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani that's what `getResources().getStringArray` does

Comment: I was assuming you had a layout with a ListView and you already knew how to set a simple ArrayAdapter<> on it.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you to retrieve string by position..

```
String[] some_array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.your_string_array)
```

Comment: Where's the adapter?

Comment: This gets the items (and I did it) but I also have to assign `id`s to each item

Comment: Resources res= getResources();
String [] item=res.getStringArray(R.array.test);

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30941803/how-to-get-items-from-a-string-array-using-an-id-based-mechanism